# Building a proper table where multiple images will be uploaded per User ID

Tags: database-schema

I am very new to PHP and MYSQL. I have gone through and made a basic schema for a relational database for the pageant website I am trying to make. I am confused on how to set up one table for the 7 images (1 headshot and 6 candid shots) that will be uploaded from each contestant and a thumbnail that will be created for each image upon a successful upload. The images will be stored in a directroy and not in the database.
I want to make sure I build the table correctly for this application. I am not sure how to create this table. Right now I have the table set up with these fields (photoID(PK), yearID(FK), photo, thumbnail)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should store the entry for only head shots, and the fields could be something like:

**(photoID(PK), yearID(FK), headshot(imageName), headshot_thumbnail, candid1_thumbnail, candid2_thumbnail, candid3_thumbnail,  candid4_thumbnail, candid5_thumbnail, candid6_thumbnail)**

The name of the candid images in your directory should be stored as headshot(imageName)_x => where x is number of candid shot ranging from 1 to 6.

This way you will not have to create new tuple for candid shots, but only the corresponding thumbnails will be stored in table.

Comment: If down the road you decide you need 7 candids, you have to change the table structure. I'd recommend against this.

Comment: I agree with Ross Presser. But, every method will have some pros and cons. Erin, you should decide based on your priority. If you are having very large number of entries, then you should go with my approach. However, If you think that in future you may require to change the number of candid shots, then this approach will not be a best solution for you.

Comment: To future proof this should I have a table for each candid shot with its thumbnail? @RossPresser